# Connected to wi-fi but Whatsapp messages won't send

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My phone is connected to the wi-fi but my Whatsapp messages won't send.  They have a clock icon next to them.

Comment: Have you tried using another wi-fi connection? If the one you're on now is routing whatsapp traffic badly, then it may cause that.

Answer (score 5):

First wait for sometime, while device is connected to wifi and it starts to auto update apps and uploading/syncing of local data backup such as photos, notes, contacts get started.

If you're seeing a syncing sign  on the top of the screen as shown in picture then wait for sometime until process ends.

[image: IMG:]

Alternatively, the other major thing could be settings turned on that is "[stop app using data in background](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-view-and-control-wi-fi-data-usage-on-android/)".

I use above settings to prevent specific apps from using heavy data in background.

Read the linked article.

Comment: Yes, I could have but someone else would have probably down voted and moved on. Next, please use quotes only for direct quotations from a source to add to your answer. Not for your answer text. Thanks for cleaning up +1

Comment: Images are also subjected to our [referencing](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) policy. That image appears to have come from [this source](https://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/lg-g4/182132d1434533099-syncing-symbol-always-whilst-charging-screenshot_2015-06-17-10-17-23.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that should fix it

1. Phone Settings
2. Apps
3. WhatsApp
4. Data Usage
5. Wi-Fi Disabled - Toggle this back to ON.